# How to prevent date variable from being updated on re-render

Tags: reactjs, date, state

I'm making a timetable grid, of sorts. It looks something like this

[image: grid]

Here's the state and helper functions for getting the data:

```
const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(startOfWeek(currentDate));
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(endOfWeek(currentDate));
  const helperDate = useRef(startDate);

  let dayList = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  ];

  const addHours = (hours, date, index) => {
    if (index === 0) return date;
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + hours * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    return date;
  };
```

And here's the div that fills the data:

```
        <div className="rabColumnTitlesWrapper">
          {Array(7)
            .fill(0)
            .map((_, i) => (
              <div className="rabColumnTitle">
                {dayList[getDay(addHours(24, helperDate.current, i))]
                  .substring(0, 3)
                  .toUpperCase()}{" "}
                <br />
                <span>{getDate(helperDate.current)}</span>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
```

The problem here is, whenever there's a state update and the components re-renders, the dates in the column titles change, whereas I want them to remain constant. How can I prevent the date from increasing when the component re-renders?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have constants inside your component, then you should declare them with `useRef`, or to simply move them out of the component. For example:

```
  const startDateRef = useRef(startOfWeek(new Date()));
  const endDateRef = useRef(endOfWeek(new Date()));
```

Comment: This is not an option, because I want to change the start and end dates on click of a button. I just don't want them to change if I'm not the one who is calling the state update.

Comment: I would need to see more details about your implementation, since I really do not understand what do you mean by "if I'm not the one who is calling the state update"? Who and how is calling `setStartDate` and `setEndDate`, and when exactly those dates change unpredictably?